# Get a field from another table in eloquent model as an attribute with a if logic

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Laravel > models >

In a table I have a **list of files** and an attribute that can be **override with a value** stored on **another table**

```
file_index (id, ..., code)

file_index_override(id, file_index_id, override_code)
```

In the file_index model, I would like to have an attribute that take the **override_code if exists** and the **code if not**. This structure is needed to run some groupBy on it.

At the moment I did

```
public function getCodeAnyAttribute() {

    return  FileIndexOverride::whereFileIndexId($this->id)->first() ? 
         FileIndexOverride::whereFileIndexId($this->id)->first()->override_code : $this->code;

}
```

But it does a single sql order on each lines, which cost a lot!

Is there a way using the power of eloquent?

Comment: If there is a relation between the two tables you can simply use the power of Eloquent Eager Loading
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: And how do use the groupBy knowing that it may be code or override_code  ? that's why i wanted to merge them in an attribute